# Connecting multiple grounds

Tags: voltage, ground

As I'm relatively new to the electronics world, I was wondering if you can connect multiple  ground terminals (corresponding to several different voltage outputs) to the same ground. Or do they each need their own?

In my case I have 5 lines, one 12V, one 3.3V, two 5V and one variable from a 12V in using a  voltage regulator that already has its own ground. So I'm guessing that each would need its own ground, but it is never bad to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have two *separated* circuits the voltages of the first don't mean anything to the second and vice versa. If you want to combine the circuits you'll have to connect a reference on one circuit with a reference on the other one. In 99 % of cases you'll choose the resp. grounds for this, because that's what ground is for: a reference against which all the rest is measured. If there's a 3 V level in a circuit, it will be referenced to ground, unless specified otherwise.

So by connecting the ground of a 5 V circuit to the ground of a 12 V circuit the 5 V becomes meaningful for that circuit as well: it will also be 5 V, or 7 V less than the 12 V.

A well designed circuit must have a reliable ground, which means that the 0 V at one point should be as close as possible to that 0 V at any other point of the ground net. Zero difference is not always possible if you're working with high currents, but the difference should be as low as possible.